# Multi level json with body response in nodejs

Tags: json, node.js

I make a request to REST Server with NodeJS and getting this type of JSON in my 'body'

```
[{
   "id": 802,
   "created": "2016-10-18 15:22:08",
   "test": {
       "name": "Fred "
    }
}]
```

log my body with JSON.parse, that is working fine for the 'root' of the JSON, but I'm not getting the 'name' in the 'test' array

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(body);
      for(index in jsonObj) {
        console.log(jsonObj[index].bag);
```

How can I make the loop and if there is a 'test' getting the data keys out ??

Comment: Can we get the code in context? Because Jamie's code should not result in undefined. If the data provided is correct.

Comment: @ahitt6345 it's working, was also a mistake in the code... the json I get it's not always have the "test" node in it... So I have to check that first and it's works like Jamie sad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work given your JSON description

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(body);
for(index in jsonObj) {
    console.log(jsonObj[index].test.name);
```